Saving many to many relation with soft-deleted relation in typeorm
I have a bill entity that it has a many-to-many relation with consumer like this:
@Entity()
export class Bill {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'bigint' })
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 18 })
  amount: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz', nullable: true })
  deletedAt: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => Consumer, (consumer) => consumer.bills, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  @JoinTable({ name: 'bill_consumer' })
  consumers: Consumer[];
}

and the consumer entity:
@Entity()
export class Consumer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
  name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz', nullable: true })
  deletedAt: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => Bill, (bill) => bill.consumers, { cascade: true })
  bills: Bill[];
}

postgres will create a new table called bill_consumer and it contains:
     bill_consumer
---------------------------
| bill_id  |  consumer_id |
--------------------------- 

everything works as expected when i create a new bill with some consumers.
const consumerOne = new Consumer();
consumerOne.name = "Jack";

const consumerTwo = new Consumer();
consumerTwo.name = "David";

const bill = new Bill();
bill.amount = 123;
bill.consumers = [consumerOne, consumerTwo];

const billRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Bill);
await billRepository.manager.save(bill);

after the creation of the bill:
     bill_consumer
---------------------------
| bill_id  |  consumer_id |
--------------------------- 
     1             1
     1             2

let's say i do a soft-delete on consumer with id 1.
the problem comes when i pass the two consumers to the bill, i receive an error which says duplicate key value violates unique constraint from the first consumer which was soft-deleted.
but there is no error when i try to update my bill with some consumers that are not soft-deleted.
i want to be able to remove or add soft-deleted consumers to a bill.
so how can i pass my soft-deleted consumers to the bill as a many-to-many relation without any error?
i have to mention that i have tried many-to-many relation with custom properties solution and i add an id to bill_consumer table and the result was not as expected. it will duplicated bill_id and consumer_id with a new id.
